# Overlapped slide still getting clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

The slide that I turned the opacity to 0 on is still clickable even though I set pointer events to none. Basically I have 2 slides on this slideshow and even if i'm on the first slide when I click on it, it goes to the 2nd slides hyperlink. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7fhv.png) This image shows the code is changing the pointer event and also the opacity correctly but for some reason when I click on the first slide on the website it still sends me to the second slides hyperlink.

```
        //programming slideshow

        $(function () {
            var slide_index = 1;
            displaySlides(slide_index);
            function nextSlide() {
                displaySlides(slide_index++);
            }
            function prevslide() {
                displaySlides(slide_index--);
            }
            function displaySlides() {
                var i;
                var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("programming-slides");
                if (slide_index > slides.length) { slide_index = 1 }
                if (slide_index < 1) { slide_index = slides.length }
                for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                    slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
                }
                slides[slide_index - 1].style.opacity = 1;
                for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                    // If the slide is not visible, set its pointer-events to none
                    if (slides[i].style.opacity === '0') {
                        slides[i].style.pointerEvents = 'none';
                    } else {
                        // Otherwise, set its pointer-events to auto
                        slides[i].style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
                    }
                }
            }
            var next = document.getElementById('programming-next');
            next.addEventListener('click', nextSlide);

            var prev = document.getElementById('programming-prev');
            prev.addEventListener('click', prevslide);
        })
```

Comment: You seem to be doing type checking as well as the value checking in your `slides[i].style.opacity === '0'`. Try to `console.log(typeof slides[i].style.opacity)`, and see whether it's a string or a number.

Comment: the console log shows it being a string

Answer (score 0):

Started to fix it by adding in z index to the code in the slides js and also to some other css elements that fixed the overlapping problem and now all the features are working

```
for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  // If the slide is not visible, set its pointer-events to none 
  if (slides[i].style.opacity === '0') {
    slides[i].style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    slides[i].style.zIndex = 0;
  } else {
    // Otherwise, set its pointer-events to auto
    slides[i].style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    slides[i].style.zIndex = 1;
  }
```